# PHP to Python Server Pages, Exit, stop page from loading

Tags: php, mod-python

I am trying to find the equivalent to php's exit command to stop a page from loading. For example I have:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

}
else{
    echo 'Your session has expired, please click <a href="https://dev.test.com/">here</a>';
    exit;
}
```

Notice the exit on the else claus..it will stop the rest of the page from loading.

Is there a way to do this in mod_pythong psp `<% exit %>`

Sys.exit(0) doesn't seem to work because now i get a HTTP 500 error, even though the logs

```
[Tue Mar 15 15:36:11 2011] [error] [client
    10.184.98.38] PythonHandler mod_python.psp:   File "/var/www/html/index.psp", line 38, in ?\n    sys.exit(0) [Tue Mar 15 15:36:11 2011] [error] [client
    10.184.98.38] PythonHandler mod_python.psp: SystemExit: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this, using [**`sys.exit`**](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) :

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

The number passed to exit being the exit code -- generally, 0 when there is no error.